# Get-ChildItem Powershell v3 missing parameter

Tags: powershell-3.0

From powershell window: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

According to docs, V3 supports the -File parameter for Get-ChildItem.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897(v=wps.620).aspx

When I run: Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $Path

 Where $Path is a variable containing a valid folder path.

I get an error:
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Everywhere I read that v3 supports this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, PowerShell **v3 - and later versions - *should* support the *dynamic* `-File` and `-Directory` switch parameters in the context of PowerShell's `FileSystem` [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers)**, as implied by [this TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4788.powershell-v3-tips-and-tricks.aspx#Links), for instance (the v3 help topics for specific cmdlets such as `Get-ChildItem` are no longer online).

v3 of *Windows PowerShell* is long obsolete:

- Its *latest* and *last* version is v5.1.x - and it will see no more active development, only security-critical fixes.
- Active development is limited to the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand successor edition, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)

However, **even in the most recent Windows PowerShell / PowerShell (Core) version it may *appear* that `-File` and `-Directory` aren't supported**, namely:

- If a (possibly positionally implied) `-Path` or a `-LiteralPath` value passed to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) happens to refer to a *non-existent drive* (or - as is to be expected - if a drive that refers to a provider *other than the file-system* is used, such as `Env:`).

  - E.g, `Get-ChildItem NoSuchDrive:\foo -Directory` predictably fails with error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory".
- Additionally, up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.4, there's a *bug* that situationally prevents even *existing* file-system paths from being recognized as targeting the file-system provider, causing  `-File` and `-Directory` to be unexpectedly unavailable, namely if (a) the *current location* isn't a file-system location and (b) `-File` or `-Directory` comes *before* a *positionally implied* `-Path` argument - see [GitHub issue #19495](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19495).

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx

These are v5.0 docs, but -file is not listed as a parameter for get-childitem.

Comment: Earlier versions of the online documentation had _separate_ - not easily discoverable - _provider-specific_ help topics. Given that `-File` and `-Directory` are _dynamic parameters_  that are specific to the `FileSystem` provider, they were _previously_ not covered in the `Get-ChildItem` help topic.  A while ago, these separate topics were _merged_, resulting in the single [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) help topic directly covering the dynamic parameters of _all_ providers, noting the provider they apply to.