# Moving files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the powershell script below.

The intent is for the script to look for a specific drawing file in my source folder and move them to another folder.

The script is also designed to check if file have already been copied and skip over those files.

the script runs it generates a text file for the list of files but is empty and does not copy any files either.

Eventually I want this to run in task scheduler

```
# Set variables
$sourceFolder = "C:\mysource\folder"
$destinationFolder = "C:\mydestination\folder"
$extensionFilter = "*.hdf"
$zipFileName = "New_Drawings_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd').zip"
$processedFilesFile = "C:\mydestination\folder\myProcessedFiles.txt"

# Check if the processed files file exists and create it if it doesn't
if (!(Test-Path $processedFilesFile)) {
    New-Item -Path $processedFilesFile -ItemType File
}

# Get the list of files that match the extension filter in the source folder and its        subfolders and haven't been processed before
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse -Filter $extensionFilter | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date -and (Get-Content $processedFilesFile) -notcontains $_.Name}

# Check if any files were found
if ($fileList.Count -gt 0) {
    # Create a new zip file with yesterday's date in the name
    $zipFileName = "New_Drawings_$(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd').zip"
    $zipFilePath = Join-Path $destinationFolder $zipFileName
    Compress-Archive -Path $fileList.FullName -DestinationPath $zipFilePath

    # Move the zip file to the source folder
    $zipFile = Get-Item -Path $zipFilePath
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $sourceFolder $zipFileName
    Move-Item -Path $zipFile.FullName -Destination $destinationPath

    # Add the names of the processed files to the processed files file
    $fileList.Name | Out-File $processedFilesFile -Append
}
```

is there a problem with my code or is it likely to be associated with a permissions issues?  There are lots of files that meet the criteria and I have also tried with other file extensions and still doesn't work

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: As an aside: Instead of using `!$_.PSIsContainer` in subsequent `Where-Object` call, add `-File` to your `Get-ChildItem` call to make it report _files_ only (as opposed to directories).

Comment: @mklement0 The intent is to identify all new files in the source folder and subfolders, zip those files and relocate them to the destination folder

Comment: Re: the -File option, note that assumes the script isn't being run on an older machine as that's not an option in PS3... think it needs PS5.

Comment: @KeithLangmead, `-File` and `-Directory` were introduced in v3 - see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4788.powershell-v3-tips-and-tricks.aspx#Links

Comment: @mklement0 Curious, by chance I was on a v3 server yesterday (Server 2012 Foundation, since updated to 5.1 so can't test now) that reported that -File was an unknown parameter, and from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213871/get-childitem-powershell-v3-missing-parameter it seems I'm not alone. Yet the docs all say it should work in v3.

Comment: @KeithLangmead, please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76232544/45375) I just posted to the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your date comparison, specifically where you have

```
$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
```

as while the Get-Date part will return :

10/05/2023 00:00:00

the LastWriteTime.Date line will return both the date and time of the file's modified date.

So rather then -eq you need -ge to catch all times AFTER midnight of the chosen day. So like this

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse -Filter $extensionFilter | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date -and (Get-Content $processedFilesFile) -notcontains $_.Name}
```

That's why if you'd tried outputting $filelist you'd have found it was empty, as none of the files were matching those conditions.

Comment: this has solved the issue of the empty list. thanks  I made one small tweak to your code with $_.FullName to get the full file path.  I am still having issue with the script zipping and moving files